# Using Heroku PostgreSql in ASP .Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, heroku

I have got my web api application deployed on Heroku, which should remember and operate (increment/decrement) certain numbers. I thought it will be a good idea to keep those numbers in database. Since this is my hobby project, I chose to connect Heroku PosgreSql add-on with free plan to my app. So here is the question: how exactly do I connect my app to this database? I have seen a lot of tutorials, but each toturial was either too overloaded with code (and little explanations to it), or described connection to local PostgreSql database (which is not what I need). I haven't do anything to this add-on except adding it to my app on app page.

Here is my Startup.cs (ConfigureServices method). ConnectionString, which I got from Postgre add-on, is located in appsettings.json.

[image: Startup.cs]

Here is DatabaseContext.cs.[image: DatabaseContext.cs]

DbService class contains methods for work with database (create new entry, edit existing, delete, etc).

I am new to web-api and databases, so I'm sorry if this question is dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku provide DATABASE_URL environment variable with connection to PostgreSQL. You need to transform provided url to efcore format `$"Server={pgHost};Port={pgPort};User Id={pgUserId};Password={pgPassword};Database={pgDatabase}";`.

Please check this topic for more info and examples https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack/issues/33

Comment: I heard that I should run migrations to create database on server. How do I do that?

Comment: Need to add PrePublishTarget to csproj with "dotnet ef database update". More info https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack#enabling-automatic-migrations

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed to connect database to my app. It works!